# A specific Fan Page ID is not returning FB Graph data

Tags: facebook, fan-page

We are working with High Times Magazine (http://www.facebook.com/HIGHTIMESMag, profile id: 23237898444). I've tried checking via FB's graph to see if the proper data returns, and it doesn't for some reason. You can check here as well:
https://graph.facebook.com/23237898444 and http://graph.facebook.com/HIGHTIMESMag

Does anyone else have this issue? How can I get the id to work, or is this a Facebook bug?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing it with a valid access token (i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/23237898444?access_token=...`) works for me. This usually means the page is age- or locale-gated.

Comment: thanks! So the Facebook social plugin for the Like box will not work with this page?  Is there any workaround or other way that we could pull their Like box into our page?

Comment: The Like Box works without any modifications, because Facebook is able to control how that's rendered for a given user, depending on their age/locale.